# Bad operands for binary operator '&&'. Please Help me find out what's wrong

Tags: java, if-statement, operands

```
 package whowins;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhoWins {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String candidate[] = {"Trump","Fiorina","Carson","Sanders"};
    String position[] = {"trumpPosition", "fiorinaPosition", "carsonPosition", "sandersPosition"};
    double supportTrump, supportFiorina, supportCarson, supportSanders;

    Scanner cs = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is Trump's support?");
    supportTrump = cs.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is Fiorina's Support?");
    supportFiorina = cs.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is Carson's support?");
    supportCarson = cs.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is Sander's support?");
    supportSanders = cs.nextDouble();

    if ((supportTrump) > (supportFiorina) && (supportCarson) && (supportSanders) {
        position[0] = ("First Place");
    }
}
}
```

The problem I am having is not being able to compare the Doubles that will be provided by the user.

`if ((supportTrump) > (supportFiorina) && (supportCarson) && (supportSanders) {`   <--------This whole line is an error and I've tried everything.

Comment: I realize there are some gaffs in my code that I'll be fixing, but the "bad operand problem is the one I can't fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`supportCarson` and `supportSanders` are not booleans, so they can't serve as operands of logical AND.

Perhaps you intended to write this :

```
if  (supportTrump > supportFiorina && supportCarson > supportSanders)
```

or this :

```
if  (supportTrump > supportFiorina && supportTrump > supportCarson &&  supportTrump > supportSanders)
```

Comment: The second would be the one that makes sense given the if-block: `position[0] = ("First Place");`

Answer (score 1):

How if statement works?

```
if (condition){
   statement
}
```

Where `condition` is an expression that returns true or false.

Now let's analyze your code.

```
if ((supportTrump) > (supportFiorina) && (supportCarson) && (supportSanders) {
    position[0] = ("First Place");
}
```

In this example condition is `(supportTrump) > (supportFiorina) && (supportCarson) && (supportSanders)`.
`&&` in Java is logical operator that means AND or just Conjunction. So, you have 3 simple conditions in your if statement:

1. supportTrump > supportFiorina (type: boolean)

   supportCarson (type: double)

   supportSanders (type: double)

All of this simple conditions must have boolean type. First condition is a boolean. But 2 others returns double type values. 
If you want to say "Execute statement in brackets if supportTrump greater than supportFiorina, supportCarson and supportSanders" you should replace this line:

```
if ((supportTrump) > (supportFiorina) && (supportCarson) && (supportSanders)
```

With this one

```
 if (supportTrump > supportFiorina && supportTrump > supportCarson && supportTrump > supportSanders)
```

Comment: Got my up-vote for being first with the right answer. My guess for the down-vote is that you don't explain why. Personally, I'd like your answer better if you had removed all those meaningless parentheses.

Comment: Your edit is an improvement, but you still don't explain anything. While "change this to that" provides a solution, it doesn't teach anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a comparison again. &&(supportCarson) is not actually comparing it. So &&(supportTrump>supportCarson) would work.